# DOM-based data storage, best choices/performances?

Tags: ajax, dom, data-binding, data-structures, load

This question is about [load data embedded into DOM structure](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-domjquery/). 
I am using jQuery2, but the question is valid for any other framework or single Javascript code.

There are two scenarios:

1. When the data is **load once** (with the page), no "refresh data" is need.
2. When data is **refreshed** by some event.

The average performance can be changed with either one or other

Suppose a typical case of scenario-2, where a page fragment must be reloaded, with new HTML and new data. So, the `$('#myDiv').load('newHtmlFragment')` will be used any way... And, for jQuery programmer, using AJAX, there are two ways to load an "DOM-based data":

- **by HTML**: expressing all data into the "newHtmlFragment" HTML. Suppose many paragraphs, each like `<p id="someId" data-X="someContent">...more content</p>`. 
  There are some "verbose overhead" for each `data-X1="contentX1" data-X2="contentX2" ...`, and is not elegant for webservice script if it is not an XHTML-oriented one (I am using PHP, my data is an array, and I preffer to use `json_encode`).
- **by jQuery evaluation**: using the same `$('#myDiv').load('newHtmlFragment')`  only for  `<p id="someId">...more content</p>`, with no `data-X`. A second AJAX load an jQuery script like `$('#someId').data(...)` and evaluate it. So this is an overhead, for node-selection and data-inclusion, but with big item-data, each data can be enconded by JSON.
- **by pure JSON**: similar to "by jQuery", but the second AJAX load an JSON object like `var ALLDATA={'someId1':{...}, 'someId2':{...}, ...}`. So this is an overhead for a static function that executes something like `$('#myDiv p').each(function(){... foreach ... $(this).data('x',ALLDATA[id]['x']);})` retrive selection, but with big data, all data can be enconded by JSON.

**The question: what the best choice?**  It depends on scenarios or another context parameter? There are signfificative performance tradeoffs?

PS: a complete answer needs to address the issue of performance... If no significative performance  differences, the best choice relies on "best programming style" and software engineering considerations.

---

More context, if you need as reference to answer. My practical problem is at scenario-1, and I am using the second choice,  "by jQuery script", executing:

```
 $('#someId1').data({'bbox':[201733.2,7559711.5,202469.4,7560794.9],'2011-07':[3,6],'2011-08':[2,3],'2011-10':[4,4],'2012-01':[1,2],'2012-02':[12,12],'2012-03':[3,6],'2012-04':[6,12],'2012-05':[3,4],'2012-06':[2,4],'2012-07':[3,5],'2012-08':[10,11],'2012-09':[7,10],'2012-10':[1,2],'2012-12':[2,2],'2013-01':[6,10],'2013-02':[19,26],'2013-03':[2,4],'2013-04':[5,8],'2013-05':[4,5],'2013-06':[4,4]});

 $('#someId2').data({'bbox':[197131.7,7564525.9,198932.0,7565798.1],'2011-07':[39,51],'2011-08':[2,3],'2011-09':[4,5],'2011-10':[13,14],'2011-11':[40,42],'2011-12':[21,25],'2012-01':[10,11],'2012-02':[26,31],'2012-03':[27,35],'2012-04':[8,10],'2012-05':[24,36],'2012-06':[4,7],'2012-07':[25,30],'2012-08':[9,11],'2012-09':[42,52],'2012-10':[4,7],'2012-11':[17,22],'2012-12':[7,8],'2013-01':[21,25],'2013-02':[5,8],'2013-03':[8,11],'2013-04':[28,40],'2013-05':[55,63],'2013-06':[1,1]});

$('#...').data(...);   ... more 50 similar lines...
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is the choice between data stored on DOM Nodes by attributes been retrieved by selectors or use JavaScript engine and create variables ( in javascript memory space ) by serialize unserialize JSON encoded data.

Comment: Thanks @cavila (!). I think I understood your considerations: in this case we can translate, what you describe, in terms of performance. As I complemented (EDITED) the question: *there are signfificative performance tradeoffs?*

Answer (score 3):

This question can be discussed from different aspects. Two that I can think of right now would be software engineering and end-user experience. A comprehensive solution covering first can also cover the later but as usually it's not possible to come up with such a solution (due to its cost) these two hardly overlap.

**Software engineering point of view**

In this POV it is strongly suggested that different parts of the system to be as isolated as possible. This means you better postpone the marriage of data and view as late as you can. It helps you to divide your developers into two separate groups; those who know server-side programming and have no idea how HTML (or any other interface layer technology) works and those who are solely experienced on HTML and Javascript. Just this division alone is a blessing for management and it helps greatly in big projects where teamwork is essential. It also helps the maintenance and expansion of the system, all the things software engineering aims at.

**User experience point of view**

As good as the previous solution sounds, it comes with (solvable) drawbacks. As you mentioned in your question, if we are to load view and data separately, it elevates the number of requests we have to send to server to retrieve them. It imposes two problems, first the overhead that comes with each request and second the delay user has to wait for each request to be responded. The second is more obvious so let's start with that. With all the advances to the Internet and bandwidths, yet our users' exceeding expectations enforce us to consider this delay. One way to reduce the number of requests would be your first choice: data within HTML fragments. Multiple number of requests also has an overhead problem as well. This can be explained by HTTP protocol's handshake (both on client-side and server-side) and by the fact that each request will lead to loading the session on server which in a large scale could be pretty considerable. So again your first option could be the answer to this problem.

**Tie breaker**

Having both sides of the story said, what then? The ultimate solution is a combination of both where data and view are married on client but they are downloaded at the same time. To be honest I don't know of such a library. But the principle is simple, you need a mechanism to package data and empty HTML fragments within the same response and combine them into what user will see on client. This solution is costy (to implement) but it is sort of the cost that once paid you can benefit from it for a life time.

Comment: Thanks, I liked your answer (!), and perhaps is enlightening to me and other readers discuss a little bit. About the *Software engineering POV* I agree, but in my case I want to use what Wikipedia say about *jQuery core features* (enabled by its selector engine): "[... created a new 'programming style', fusing algorithms and DOM-data-structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)". So, in this context, the *coupling* as "fusing algorithms and DOM-data-structures" is a wanted feature; and the *by jQuery evaluation* solution (see question) preserves the "blessing division" for teamwork.

Comment: Edited question: only to reinforce the performance problem (see the  bounty text).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on *how* you are going to use the data that is stored. Consider this example:

### Example

You have 300 items in a database (say server access logs of the last 300 days). Now you want to display 300 `<div>` tags, each tag representing one database-item.
Now there are 2 options to do this:

```
<div data-stat1="stat1" data-stat2="stat2" data-stat3="stat3">(...)</div>
<!-- again, this is repeated 300 times -->

<script>
// Example on how to show "stat1" value in all <div>s
function showStat1() {
  for(var i=1; i<=300; i+= 1) {
    var theID = '#id-' + i;
    jQuery(theID).text(jQuery(theID).data('stat1'));
  }
}
</script>
```

OR

```
<div id="id-1">(...)</div>
<!-- repeat this 300 times, for all DB items -->

<script>
data = { // JSON data which is displayed in the <div> tags
  '1': ['stat1', 'stat2', 'stat3'],
  // same for all 300 items
}

// Example on how to show "stat1" value in all <div>s
function showStat1() {
  for(var i=1; i<=300; i+= 1) {
    var theID = '#id-' + i;
    jQuery(theID).text(data[i][0]);
  }
}
</script>
```

### Which scenario is better?

**Case 1**:
The data is directly coded into the DOM elements, which makes this one an easy to implement solution. You can see in my examples that the first code block takes a lot less code to generate and the code is less complex.

This solution is very powerful, when you want to store data that is directly related to an DOM element (as you do not have to create a logical connection between JSON and DOM): It is very simple to access data for the correct element.

However, your main concern is performance - this is NOT the way to go. Because every time you access data, you have to first select the correct DOM element and attribute via javascript, which takes considerable amount of time. So the simplicity costs you a lot of performance overhead when you want to read/write data in the element.

**Case 2**:
This scenario very cleanly separates the DISPLAY from the DATA storage. It has major advantages compared to the first case.

A) Data should not be mingled with the display elements - imagine you want to switch from `<div>` to `<table>` and suddenly you have to rewrite all javascript to correctly select the correct table cells

B) Data is directly accessible without traversing the DOM tree. Imagine you want to calculate an average sum of all values. In first case you need to loop all DOM elements and read value from them. In the second you simply loop a normal array

C) The data can be loaded or refreshed via ajax. You only transfer the JSON object but not all the HTML stuff that is required for displaying the data

D) **Performance** is way better, mostly because of the above mentioned points. Javascript is a lot better in handling simple arrays or (not too complex) JSON objects than it is in filtering data out of the DOM tree.

In general this solution is more than twice as fast as the first case. You will also discover - even though it is not obvious - that the second case is also easier to code and maintain! The code simply is easier to read and understand, as you clearly separate the data from the UI elements...

### Performance comparison

You can compare the two solutions on this JSPerf scenario: 
http://jsperf.com/performance-on-data-storage

### Taking it further

For implementation of the second case I generally use this approach:

1. I generate the HTML code which will serve as the UI. It often happens that I have to generate HTML via javascript, but now I assume that the DOM tree will not change after the page is loaded
2. At the end of the HTML I include a  tag with a JSON object for initial page display
3. Via jQuery onReady event I then parse the JSON object and update the UI elements as required (e.g. populating the table with data)
4. When data is loaded dynamically I simply transfer a new JSON object with the new data and use exact the same javascript function as in step 3 to display the new results.

Example of the HTML file:

```
<div>ID: <span class="the-id">-</span></div>
<div>Date: <span class="the-date">-</span></div>
<div>Total page hits: <span class="the-value">-</span></div>
<button type="button" class="refresh">Load new data</button>

<script src="my-function.js"></script>
<script>
function initial_data() {
    return {"id":"1", "date":"2013-07-30", "hits":"1583"};
}  
</script>
```

The "my-function.js" file:

```
jQuery(function initialize_ui() {
    // Initialize the global variables we will use in the app
    window.my_data = initial_data();
    window.app = {};
    app.the_id = jQuery('.the-id');
    app.the_date = jQuery('.the-date');
    app.the_value = jQuery('.the-value');
    app.btn_refresh = jQuery('.refresh');

    // Add event handler: When user clicks refresh button then load new data        
    app.btn_refresh.click(refresh_data);

    // Display the initial data
    render_data();
});

function render_data() {
    app.the_id.text(my_data.id);
    app.the_date.text(my_data.date);
    app.the_value.text(my_data.hits);
}

function refresh_data() {
    // For example fetch and display the values for date 2013-07-29
    jQuery.post(url, {"date":"2013-07-29"}, function(text) {
        my_data = jQuery.parseJSON(text);
        render_data();
    });
}
```

*I did not test this code. Also there is crucial error handling and other optimization missing. But it helps to illustrate the concepts that I try to describe*